# An efficient way to read/write a large scene file

Tags: c++, multithreading, io

I have a large scene (containing millions or even billions of polygons in multiple meshes) file to be loaded or written into an in-house game engine, I am wondering if anyone can give me a hint about what's the fastest way to load that scene file.

I have done a little research online and there are three major ways in file loading: reading/writing in chunks, file mapping and reading/writing on multiple threads. I've also learned that it seems inappropriate to use multiple threads if the program reads/writes a single file. Therefore, it looks like managing all data in the whole scene as a huge chunk of memory to be read/written using fread()/fwrite() (methods in c++) is a good option in my scene loading/writing mechanism. I am wondering what are the pros and cons of each file loading/writing approaches and if fread()/fwrite() is good enough in handling a IO process of a large scene file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never done anything like that before, but you could try to create an index of every object in the scene, and their location in the file. Then it's easy to do on-demand loading, so you only load the objects that can be seen, and the surrounding objects. When the player turns load the surrounding objects already loaded and remove the objects no longer in the immediate surroundings. For example, if the player can't see behind him, there's no need to have that data loaded. If this is good or effective I don't know, just thought of it of the top of my head.

Comment: Your on-demand loading sounds a good solution and it does save memory as it avoid loading and rendering unnecessary objects in the scene. However, our engine would probably like to keep all objects as it keeps option open for other editors to edit the scene. Moreover, would the process be slow when it frequently call I/O functions and access file saved on disc?

Comment: It is very probably OS and even filesystem specific

Comment: It could be worth considering compressing the file. If your data compresses reasonably it can give a good boost. Compression/decompression can also be threaded, so it can be performed while the reader/writer is waiting for the I/O.

Comment: Hardware matters, too.  There's no point in doing multithreaded reads/writes from/to different parts of the file if the storage is a single, slow 5400 rpm SATA drive that can only do 50 random IO operations/sec but can still stream 80-100 MB/sec.  If that's the storage, a single thread doing large sequential reads/writes would be best.  What's your target hardware?  Consumer-grade with single SATA drives on mediocre (at best) controllers?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you'll code, quite probably, the hardware would be the bottleneck (so no software tricks could alleviate that).

<sup>(I am guessing you are on Linux)</sup>

You could use demand-reading and use some higher level library like [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/).

If you do low level IO (so *without* such libraries), consider using perhaps the Linux specific [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) and more probably [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) (or [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) if you `mmap`)

Of course, good buffering is essential (if using `<stdio.h>`, which is probably more efficient than C++ streams, consider [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html)...)

Comment: Actually so far we are working on Windows, but platforms on Linux will be our next step. Your suggestions are very helpful, thank you.